# Mocking objects of protected methods in java

Tags: java, mockito, protected

Below is my code design. I need guidance, how to write the test case for it.

```
abstract class X
{
    public void xyz()
    {
        A a = getA();
        callMe(a);
    }
    private A getA()
    {
          //do some stuff
          return a;
    }
    protected void callMe();
}
```

Below is the child class:

```
class Y extends X
{
    @Autowired
    MyClass myClass;

    protected void callMe(A a)
    {
         B b = provideB();
         C c = b.getC();
         c.setValue(myClass.getSomeValue());
    }
    private B provideB()
    {
        //every child class has its own way of providing this object
        return b;
    }      
}
```

Now, I am writing unit test cases for child class Y, So I am calling xyz method for testing. I know that I need to mock MyClass object as it is my external dependency. So I mocked it. But I am confused that should I mock A and thus subsequently B and C as well or as they are being created somehow in protected/private methods subsequently so, should I just let its creation happen while testing?
Any lead will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I only test the public interface of a class. So I would only call `xyz()` and check that it respects its contract. Since A, B and C are not injected, then they are not part of the public interface and I wouldn't mock them.

Now about whether you should inject them or not. It depends on what kind of objects A, B and C are. If they are small, dumb objects (value objects for instance) then you will be just fine creating them in private/protected methods. If they are somewhat larger objects, and especially if you could conceivably someday want to use a different implementation of them, then you should inject them and mock them. If you want the X class to control the lifetime of these objects, you can inject a Factory instead, and replace any calls to `new` with calls to the factory.